# Clearing a faulty service in WSo2

Tags: service, proxy, wso2, esb

I have recently built a proxy service in WSo2 ESB that was not fully implemented. When I saved it generated a fault service message and a link was provided to a faulty service group at the top of the ESB console. Since then, I have corrected the service and it has been transferring files as I have intended. However the service does not show in the initial list of services and I have to click on the link 7 deployed service group(s) to now view it in the proxy list.

Here is what the link looks like:
*6 active services.  7 deployed service group(s). 1 faulty service(s).*

When I click on the 1 faulty service(s) I see the following but cannot delete it in an attempt to clear it.

```
*Faulty Service     Actions
RenZipExtractProxy proxy

Unable to configure the service RenZipExtractProxy for the VFS transport: Service doesn't have configuration information for transport vfs. This service is being marked as faulty and will not be available over the VFS transport.*
```

How do I clear this faulty service issue? My updated service works fine but I continue to get the faulty service situation as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually delete deployment artifacts in the directory `<ESB>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services`

Comment: My understanding is by doing that it removes the proxy service as a whole. However I corrected the service and it seems to be working fine. How do i remove the fault services listed on the faulty services screen? I guess i was under the impression i should be able to clear those? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that when we configure WSO2 esb with VFS protocol and do not provide any parameter then it is going under Faulty service. I resolved this problem after mentioning VFS related parameters.

Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/VFS+Transport

**Note:** If we try to delete faulty proxy service from console then also it will not deleted. Please try to delete it from file system.

```
<ESB_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/proxy-services
```